# UIView Animation not shown after segue

Tags: swift, uiview, uicollectionview, uilabel, uiviewanimation

I have 2 View Controllers. The first one is a Collection View Controller, the second a plain View Controller. When clicking a cell in the Collection View Controller, the second View Controller appears. When the view starts to load in the 2nd view controller, I want to show a `UILabel` sliding from the top to the center of the screen .

**Problem**: the animation doesn't take place. The `UIlabel` appears directly in the center, then disappears as coded after 3 seconds. What am I’m doing wrong?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Add a label to the view
    var dynamicLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
    dynamicLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, 60)
    dynamicLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    dynamicLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    dynamicLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    dynamicLabel.text = "test label"
    self.view.addSubview(dynamicLabel)

    // animation
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity:3.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: ({dynamicLabel.center.y = self.view.frame.height/2}), completion: { animationFinished in
        // when complete, remove the UILabel from the parent view
        self.delay(3.0) {
            dynamicLabel.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }) 
}
```

Comment: Put your animation in `override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)`.

Comment: In viewdidload the layout haven't shown yet. Take Daniel advice and update us

Comment: Thank you so much guys! You are absolutely right! It works :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move your `Animation` block into `viewDidAppear()`